# Source of Maine's "Ayuh"?

Tags: dialects

What's the etymology of this Maine synonym for "yes"? I've always wondered. OTOH, "finest kind" is pretty obvious.

Comment: Livermore Falls is the source, probably. But no one knows the source of the Androscoggin River. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following source the suggested origin from  nautical jargon is discussed  and a new origin  is put  forward;  a  Scottish one.

**[Ajuh](http://dialectblog.com/2011/04/14/ayuh-americas-oddest-yes/)**: (from www.dialectblog.com)

> - This word is the informal version of “yes” in Maine, and, unusually for semi-archaic dialect words, it has more of a standardized spelling than it does a pronunciation. I’ve usually heard it as eh-YUH (IPA eɪˈjʌ), but there’s also a pronunciation that puts more weight on the first syllable (EY-yuh), as well as EE-yuh or eye-yuh.
> - In *Facts on File Dictionary of American Regionalisms* by Robert Hendrickson. Quoth Mr. Hendrickson (emphasis his):
>
>   - Chiefly heard in Maine,**ayuh** is found throughout New England … A touch stone of New England speech, *it possibly derives from the nautical **aye** (yes), which in turn probably comes from the early English **yie** (yes). Another theory has **ayuh** coming from the old Scots-American **aye-yes** meaning the same.

- I might be willing to buy the Scottish explanation for a few reasons:

> - 1 - Maine was one of the areas where the Scots-Irish initially settled. In fact, you can see in this [map](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/29/Scotch_irish1346.gif) that a large percentage of people of Scots-Irish descent is found in precisely the area where the “Down East” accent is heard.
> - 2 -  In most varieties of ayuh the “ay” rhymes with “day.” This more closely resembles the modern Scottish pronunciation of Aye than in other areas where Aye is heard.
> - 3) The aye yes that Hendrickson mentions appear to be a feature of some Scottish English dialects to this day. Although be aware that I am deducing this from some very circumstancial evidence (such as this message board). So take this last bit with a huge grain of salt.

Comment: I've only heard it pronounced "aye-uh" as in "aye-aye". But I think the nautical explanation makes the most sense, because of its prevalence along the coast.

Comment: I always thought that "aye" was a cognate of Old English "ā", meaning "forever".